# Hoax LIMIT value

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there a value that used with a LIMIT clause means nothing or no limit?

I'd expected that `0` would be that value but it obviously isn't:

```
SELECT * FROM items LIMIT 0 -- returns 0 rows
```

Comment: I assume there's a reason you can't just omit the limit clause altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a value far outside the number of records you're actually retrieving:

```
LIMIT 0, 18446744073709551615
```

[Quote](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter.

Comment: I was hoping a more elegant approach existed.

Comment: Is the `0, ` part necessary? I'd expect that just `LIMIT 18446744073709551615` would work the same way.

Comment: @Emanuil: Zero is the notation for accessing the first element in an array - very common in programming.  You can omit the first parameter if you want the records to limit based on the first position.